# GAE database (CloudSQL) access with narrow IP6 subnet

Tags: database, ip, google-cloud-sql

I'm on a network that changes my IP6 address couple times a day and can't assign me an IP4 address. GAE database (CloudSQL) access is defined by whitelist of allowed IPs. For IP6 addresses only XXX/128 (i.e. 1 address) and XXX/127 (i.e. 2 addresses) are allowed so I can't define wider set of IPs.

Thus when I access GAE database I have to change whitelist couple times a day, which is quite annoying. Is there any way to get around it?

Comment: by GAE database do you mean datastore? How do you access the datastore? I'm not aware there's such a feature like whitelist.

Comment: I mean CloudSQL. I've edited my question to make it clear.